# Can I use isEditable() on a global?

Tags: globals

I have a `headline` global.

I am trying to see if `headline` is editable by using this code block, but it is not working.

Can I use `isEditable()` with my `headline` global?

```
{% if headline.isEditable() %}
    <div class="admin-edit-button-wrapper">
        <a href="{{ headline.cpEditUrl }}" class="admin-edit-button">Edit Headline</a>
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`isEditable()` would be a method of the content model, not of a field. Unfortunately, this is currently only useful for *[EntryModel](https://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/models/EntryModel#isEditable-detail)* objects; It is not presently implemented for *GlobalSetModel* objects, so using `.isEditable` on a global set will always [return `false`](https://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/models/BaseElementModel#isEditable-detail).

However, you could use the [`.can()`](https://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/models/UserModel#can-detail) method on a user, and check for the permission `'editglobalset:X'` (where *X* is the ID of your Global Set element).

For example — assuming `header` is a *GlobalSetObject* you have fetched elsewhere in your template):

```
{% if currentUser and currentUser.can('editglobalset:' ~ header.id) %}
...
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Good call on the `currentUser.can` approach – definitely easier than creating a custom plugin!

Answer (score 4):

No, the `isEditable` property isn't supported for Global Sets.

The confusing thing is that the [`GlobalSetModel`](https://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/models/GlobalSetModel) class does actually have an [`isEditable`](https://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/models/BaseElementModel#isEditable-detail) property, however it will always return `false`. The reason is that this property is inherited from the `BaseElementModel` class, where it will return `false` *unless the element type overrides it to (potentially) return something else*. An example of the latter is the `EntryModel` class, which also inherits `BaseElementModel` but overrides  `isEditable` [to test if the current user is allowed to edit the entry](https://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/models/EntryModel#isEditable-detail).

It'd be interesting to hear P&T's reasoning for not "enabling" `isEditable` for Global Sets, although to be honest – needing to give users the ability to edit global variables from the frontend sounds like an edge case at best, and probably not a very good idea.

*On that note, my best advice for a workaround would be to simply use a Single instead of a Global Set.*

However, if you need/want to use a Global Set, you can easily work around the issue by creating a custom plugin exposing a `isGlobalSetEditable` template variable method. Something like this should work:

```
public function isGlobalSetEditable(GlobalSetModel $globalSet)
{
    return craft()->userSession->checkPermission('editGlobalSet:'.$globalSet->id);
}
```

In your template, you could then do something like this:

```
{% if craft.myPlugin.isGlobalSetEditable(headline) %}
    <a href="{{ headline.cpEditUrl }}">Edit me</a>
{% endif %}
```

If you're not familiar with plugin development, I'd advice you to check out the [official docs on the subject](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/introduction), and to download the excellent [Business Logic Plugin](https://github.com/lindseydiloreto/craft-businesslogic) as a starting point – it even has a Variable class where the above `isGlobalSetEditable` method could be dropped right in.